# Passing multiple sets of arguments to a command

Tags: command-line, bash, xargs, command-line-arguments

`instances` contains several whitespace separated strings, as does `snapshots`.
I want to run the command below, with each instance-snapshot pair.

```
ec2-attach-volume --instance $instances --device /dev/sdf $snapshots
```

For example, if `instances` contains `A B C`, and `snapshots` contains `1 2 3`, I want the command to be called like so:

```
ec2-attach-volume -C cert.pem -K pk.pem --instance A --device /dev/sdf 1
ec2-attach-volume -C cert.pem -K pk.pem --instance B --device /dev/sdf 2
ec2-attach-volume -C cert.pem -K pk.pem --instance C --device /dev/sdf 3
```

I can do either one or the other with `xargs -n 1`, but how do I do both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `bash` shell, one possible method is:

```
instances=( `cat instances` )
snapshots=( `cat snapshots` )

for i in ${!instances[@]}; do
    ec2-attach-volume -C cert.pem -K pk.pem \
        --instance ${instances[i]} --snapshot ${snapshots[i]}
done
```

Here `${!instances[@]}` expands to all indexes of the `instances` array (0, 1, 2, and so on). You can examine the array contents by doing `declare -p instances snapshots` after the first two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an approach that includes (some) error handling:

```
xargs –n 1 < instances > instances.1_per_line    # “xargs –n 1” is equivalent to
xargs –n 1 < snapshots > snapshots.1_per_line    # “xargs –n 1 echo”.
if [ $(wc –l < instances.1_per_line)  !=  $(wc –l < snapshots.1_per_line) ]
then
        echo "Different numbers of strings." >&2
else
        paste instances.1_per_line snapshots.1_per_line | while read inst snap
        do
                ec2-attach-volume -C cert.pem -K pk.pem --instance "$inst" \
                                --device /dev/sdf "$snap"
        done
fi
rm instances.1_per_line snapshots.1_per_line
```

This may work better than [grawity’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/492892) for large files, as it doesn’t need to read the files into memory. 
And this may work better in older versions of `bash`. 
(If `$(command)` doesn’t work, try `` `command` ``.) 
On the other hand, my answer will fail
if any of the strings in the files contain quote characters.

Answer (score 1):

To do it in parallel you can use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel --xapply ec2-attach-volume --instance {1} --device /dev/sdf {2} ::: `cat instances` ::: `cat snapshots`
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1